# gcloud endpoints deploy error unresolved type

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm trying to deploy a service which requires [google protobuf's Timestamp](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto) but I am receiving an error.

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy api_descriptor.pb api_config.yaml --validate-only

ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot 
convert to service config.
'ERROR: unknown location: Unresolved type '.google.protobuf.Timestamp''
```

my command to generate api_descriptor.pb:

```
protoc \
--plugin=protoc-gen-go=${GOBIN}/protoc-gen-go \
-I . proto/service.proto \
--descriptor_set_out=api_descriptor.pb \
--go_out=plugins=grpc:. \
```

relevant bit from proto file which requires google.protobuf.Timestamp:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package proto;

import "vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp/timestamp.proto";

message CandleStick {
    string ID = 1;
    double Open = 2;
    double Close = 3;
    double High = 4;
    double Low = 5;

    google.protobuf.Timestamp TimeStamp = 6;
}
```

Tried for hours unsuccessfully to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recent versions of the proto compiler include timestamp.proto, so you don't need to vendor it any more.  You can use:  import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your protoc command line invocation, I think you need to include all the imports in the generated descriptor.  You can do this using `--include_imports`:

```
protoc \
--plugin=protoc-gen-go=${GOBIN}/protoc-gen-go \
--include_imports \
-I . proto/service.proto \
--descriptor_set_out=api_descriptor.pb \
--go_out=plugins=grpc:. \
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I thought I had to include a path with the include_imports tag.